# Total wires in a receptacle duplex box

Tags: wiring

What is the most 14 ga copper wires (hot/neutral) according to NEC should fit in a duplex receptacle standard(single gang)  outlet metal box? This number should also include piggybacks?

Comment: Precisely what size is this box? Does it have a device in it?

Comment: Does it have anything about cubic inches listed on the box?  Most do.

Answer (score 2):

Table 314.16.A provides box fill for standard boxes:

- a 3x2x1-1/2 box is listed for 3ea 14 gauge conductors (7.5 cu inch box)
- a 3x2x3-1/2 box can have 9# 14 conductors (18 cu inch box)

The calculation for #14 wire is

```
    # of conductors x 2 cu in. + 2 cu. in. for all the grounds. (Only count 1x for all the grounds.)
  + 4 cu in. per device 
  + 1x if the box has clamps (1x 2 cu. in.) only count 1 even if there are more.
  = total cu inches or less is acceptable unless an extension ring/adapter is possible ( referred to as plaster/mud rings can add to the total value and will be stamped on the extender or mud rings).
```

If using # 12 wire the multiplier would be 2.25 to give an idea for different wire sizes.
Note that just measuring the box will provide the wrong value. The stamped value is usually smaller than the measured value.

Comment: Can you please check if my edit is correct?

Comment: Looks ok to me.

Comment: Had to edit it too.  Was little bit unclear as to what x 2 was representing.

Comment: Kris some of your edits are wrong only count 1 x for clamps with the largest wire size entering the box and my spelling is bad enough without you adding misspelled words but some one else must be working on it because the system won't let me fix them and I don't see it up for review of edits.

Comment: When you're tired things appear spelled correctly :-) ... will make note about the clamp...